# Ruby on Rails: Can I route a request directly to a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have an admin section that has a sub-directory of the `controllers` directory. I.e., the directory `app/controllers/admin/` holds a set of files, each containing a controller for handling a separate portion of the admin section.

Now, I want to create a very simple ''admin homepage'' that just says something a la "welcome to the admin section", but I want to avoid creating an entire controller for this purpose, or placing the "action" method for this view in some other, arbitrary controller.

So, the question is, is there a way to route ''directly to a view'' -- to route directly to an HTML file?  (And, I don't want to route to an HTML file from a requested path like `/some-file.html`; I need to route from a path like `/admin/`.)

Asking this question here is hardly worth the time it takes to create a stub controller, but I'm sure I will have such a need again in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. Why?

Design: It's just a violation of the MVC pattern Rails enforces you to use, for your own good. There is always a controller involved. And yes, even for such stub pages, a controller is required. Anyway, a few lines of code won't hurt you, and you'll love it again when you need to perform some access control.

Hope that answered your question :-)

Answer (score 8):

Like moritz says, you can't completely bypass the controller, but you do not necessarily have to create an entire controller just for this action. When I need a "dashboard" or "landing" type of page, I just add the action to my ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def index
  end
end
```

Then put your page at app/views/application/index.html.erb

For your case, you can put an application_controller.rb in your app/controllers/admin/ directory, and do the same thing there.

I find that this is the perfect place for pages that fall outside of a resource.

Comment: Would the mysterious downvoter care to explain why this isn't a good idea? I've been doing it for a while and it works for me, but I'm open to the idea that I may be doing it wrong.

Comment: Ben: Your idea was helpful to me in early testing of a layout. Thanks.

Comment: New in town with Rails but under my point of view, this is not really nice. Is there a better solution? It's weird to have a class with some empty methods.

Comment: Hello from the past! In the four years since I answered this question, I've started doing things a little differently, but not by much. I now just create a HomeController with an empty index action. IIRC there was disagreement in rails core about whether to make my answer above the default. Either way you do it, the action will be empty if your page doesn't require the controller to do anything *shrug*.