# Can I Render A Layout Directly From routes.rb, Without A Controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, layout, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I would like to set up a pair of style guides for the admin and public sections of a website.

Each will need its own layout which will contain a mixture of static html and calls to erb partials (so a static page won't cut it). I have no need of a controller(s) to serve these pages and I don't want what is effectively development-only content cluttering up the rest of the code. This got me wondering whether there is a way to render a layout directly.

*Disclaimer: I appreciate this is not something I should do often/ever and I know there are a wealth of arguments for why this is a bad idea. I am interested in whether this is possible.*

**Is there a way for me to render a layout directly from `routes.rb` without going through a controller?**

Comment: @jvnill My component-style partials are all configured through locals, so I can pass dummy data into them. They don't use controller variables. Mostly the layout is static.

Comment: sorry, deleted my comment because i thought you removed the erb partials in your question.  in any case, the routes is just a way to match the urls to a controller action.  i'm not sure i follow why there's no need for a controller.  even if you use local variables in rendering the partials, where do you call `render` from?

Comment: @jvnill That's kind of the point of my question. I'm interested in whether there is a way of rendering it without a controller. Maybe the answer is that it's not possible, but I'm interested in whether it is.

Comment: yes, i don't think there is.  it's not just about the layout though.  if the content isn't static, you'd have to go through a controller or use @Зелёный's answer and use ERB binding but that's basically what the controller does.

Comment: You will get an uninitialized constant error when you make the request without the correspond controller.

Answer (score 11):

For some weird reason I wanted to render a blank JS file for a while, and writing a controller felt like too much for this kind of hack. Thanks to @genkilabs 's answer, I used this 3 liner:

```
get 'analytics/some_file.js', to: -> (env) do
  [200, { 'Content-Type' => 'application/javascript' }, ['']]
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do something really stupid once, so if you do too, try this working example.

```
match :movedpage, :to => proc { |env|
    if Rails.env.production?
        @remote_path = 'http://productionhost.com'
    elsif Rails.env.staging?
        @remote_path = 'http://staginghost.com'
    else
        @remote_path = 'http://localhost:3000'
    end
    [
        200,
        {"Content-Type" => "text/html"},
        [File.read("public/moved_page.html").gsub('@remote_path', @remote_path)]
    ]
}, :via => :all
```

Where moved_page.html was a static page asking people up update their bookmarks and @remote_path just typed in a link like `<a href="@remote_path">@remote_path</a>`. Note that `<%= %>` won't work because you don't have view helpers in there.

So, theres enough rope to get yourself in trouble ^_^

Answer (score -1):

Actualy the answer is **NO**, you can't do it without a controller. But see some trivial workaround...

It's not very fair but should work:

Assuming you have `FooController` with any logic you already have implemented. Now you want to render `anypage.html.erb` without creating any special controller. Here is how:

---

1. Configure a route to your static page:

   `get '/your/static/page', to: 'foo#anypage'`
2. Implement the view `app/views/foo/anypage.html.erb`.

---

The problem is that it is impossible to change a path to your view. The path depends on the controller that you specify in a route (`foo` in the example). Also note that it will be rendered with a specified for `FooController` layout.

It should work by convention and you can read about it [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-by-default-convention-over-configuration-in-action).

---

UPDATE

Also I found very simmilar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1971810/3797480). Using ApplicationController seems more reasonable for such pages. (Note that **you needn't to create an action for it**)