# Routes to Specific View in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm learning Ruby on Rails. I have a login page that has a layout that is completely different than the rest of the site. Inside of my routes.rb, how to I tell the application to always render this particular page using the "login" view instead of the default "application" view?

Comment: You can handle it in your login controller, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025784/rails-layouts-per-action

Comment: Can it not be done in the routes.rb for some reason?

Comment: Nope. Looks like a design choice of the framework, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982111/can-i-render-a-layout-directly-from-routes-rb-without-a-controller

Comment: Thanks for the link that was very helpful

Answer (score 3):

In Rails 4, you can use: `render layout: 'some_layout'` to render a specific layout.

In your controller's `login` method, you can have something like this:

```
def login
  # do stuff
  if some_condition
    # do stuff
    render layout: 'some_condition_layout'
  else
    # do other stuff
    render layout: 'some_other_layout'
  end
end
```

For more information on renderings and layouts, you can check out [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can call render layout on each action as per [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32162927/1438508) or you can do the following to [dynamically set the layout name depending on the action name:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3025806/1438508):

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    layout :resolve_layout

    def index
    end

    def home
    end

    def dashboard
    end

    private
        def resolve_layout
            case action_name
            when "home" #action name
                "home" #layout name
            when "dashboard"
                "dashboard"
            else
                "application"
            end
        end

end
```